# How to access apollo object inside custom-editor.component extended by Handsontable.editors.AutocompleteEditor

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, handsontable, hasura

*How I can access this.apollo object inside that custom-edior.component.ts file*

I am using Handsontable in angualr project. Data stored in Hasura. To communicate with Hasura, I am using Apollo client. handsontable privde a feature to customise editor for cell or column, I m trying to customise automcompletesuggstion type editor but receving an error.

Here is my code where I have replicated issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a87e7k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts*your text*

Comment: I do not see any errors (if you mean the console) but you seem to miss the CSS file "@import '~handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css';"